# Downloading to CD, want to make sure I'm doing it right

Tags: laptop, cd

I've got an ancient **Umax 333T** laptop that's pretty much dead, but I was wondering if I could breathe new life into it by downloading a free OS. That brought me here.
[Download Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download)

1. If I download it to my PC's hard drive, will it automatically change anything on my PC?
2. Do I then burn to CD and try on laptop?
   Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Downloading the image will just result in you having the file on your PC ready for writing to CD.
You will then need to burn it to a CD, reboot the laptop so it boots from the CD.

You can then try Ubuntu without installing anything until you are happy that it is what you want to do.

Nothing will be installed or altered unless you want it to be.

You can find out more about it before you start from [the page you found](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download) by following the "show me how" buttons.

If you want to try Ubuntu from within windows, take a look at the [windows installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/windows-installer).

Answer (score 1):

Downloading the iso will not affect your computer.

You may need software to burn the  CD, see

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto

In addition, you can use unetbootin to use a flash drive rather then a cd if you wish.

http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

When booting the CD / USB you can try Ubuntu and test your hardware. Again, bu default it will not affect your computer, although it could if you do something without understanding what you are doing.

If you wish to install, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall

Be sure to back up your data first . Although data loss is rare, it can happen.

In addition, be sure you understand partitioning.